# Updating Roles in rolify using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancan, rolify

Using Rails 4.0, ActiveAdmin, Rolify and CanCan, Adding and removing user roles via the activeadmin panel does not save (commit to database).

The my [ActiveAdmin User and User Model](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/7874594) look okay as I can list all the roles that apply to a user using check_boxes. Although when adding any roles or removing any roles via the checkboxes the changes do not get applied.

[image]

I get a notification that the user was updated successfully but as I look through the database or render the page, the roles have not been updated.

How can I get the roles to update when the form is saved?

Edit:

Using Devise also.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution here is to allow the ActiveAdmin controller to update the role ids related to the user.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, role_ids: []
```

Here's a form that shows a check box for each global role.

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :roles, as: :check_boxes
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

While we're at it, we might as well make it possible to update the user without entering their password:

```
  # Allow form to be submitted without a password
  controller do
    def update
      if params[:user][:password].blank?
        params[:user].delete "password"
        params[:user].delete "password_confirmation"
      end

      super
    end
  end
```

Put all of this in the **app/admin/user.rb**.

Comment: You could also add this line to update the user roles `params[:user][:role_ids].each {|role_id| resource.add_role Role.find(role_id) if Role.exists?(id: role_id) }`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.  The problem was with validation of presence (which I think is occurring in the database ":null => :false").  In order for the update to save, I had to fill out all fields (including password/password confirmation).

Comment: It seems to not be saving with all the fields. Even entering the password is not allowing data to be saved to the record.

Comment: Are you displaying all the fields that belong to the model?  I wasn't displaying the email field, but if you look at your migration file for the user it should say which fields require an entry.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some controller code to make this work, I hope this helps:

Remember to permit the attributes you're accepting in active_admin as such (this will create the `permitted_params` method I'll be referring to in a bit.

Note that since we're not saving role_ids directly to the user, it doesn't even have to be a permitted param.

```
  permit_params :email, :password, :etc
```

Create a private method we could call from the create and update controllers. This method will just iterate over non-empty ids, find the associated roles, and add them to `user.roles`.

The create and update methods simply find call the `add_roles` method prior to continuing execution. ActiveAdmin makes the the existing user available through `resource`, but not through create. We have to find it ourselves in create!

```
  controller do
    def create
      @user = User.new(permitted_params[:user])
      add_roles(@user)
      create!
    end

    def update
      add_roles(resource)
      update!
    end

    private
    def add_roles(resource)
      resource.roles = []
      params[:user][:role_ids].each { |r| resource.roles.push(Role.find(r)) unless r.blank? }
    end
  end
```

In the activeadmin form, you can add:

```
  form do |f|
    # other inputs
    f.input :roles, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: Role.all
  end
```

And in the show page, you can display the roles as such:

```
  show do
    attributes_table do
      # other rows
      row :roles do |r|
        r.roles.map { |role| role.name }.join(", ")
      end
    end
```

Hope this helps!